# How to set up sub domains with IIS 7.5?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, domain-name

I'm in the process of setting up a windows 2008 server. I've managed to set up a site on IIS and I'm in the process of setting up a few more.

Typically when setting up sites on my local machine, I update the hosts file with the relevant domain names I'd like to use and point them to localhost.

This is the first time I've set up a live web server and I wonder how I can get multiple subdomains to point to their respective sites.

For example, I've registered mydomain.com with a hosting company and have updated the A records to point to my new server IP. (I've tested this and it's working fine).

However now I'd like to create, say 3 sites, within IIS with the following urls:

mysite1.mydomain.com
mysite2.mydomain.com
mysite3.mydomain.com

If this was my local machine I'd simply update the hosts file to route these domains to 127.0.0.1. Is this how it works on the live server? Do I still have to update the hosts file every time I add a site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't touch the hosts file.

All you should do is to create the appropiate A-records at your hosting provider and setup the sites in IIS and you are good to go.

Remember to change the bindings so they are correct according to the domain it serves.

Comment: Ah yes I see now. The hosts file only needs to be used on the local machine since any requests made to the domain need to be routed to the localhost..